# Using EasyJSON with golang

Tags: json, go

Let's say I have a struct like below:-

```
//easyjson:json
type JSONData struct {
    Data []string
}
```

I want to un-marshal the below json to `JSONData` struct

```
{"Data" : ["One", "Two", "Three"]}
```

Can someone let me know how can I use [easyjson](https://github.com/mailru/easyjson) to un-marshal a json in Golang? I could not find any example in their `README`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you trying to use easyjson. encoding/json is pretty fine to work with. But though here is the answer for you.

NB: **It would be better if you use encoding/json.**

```
//easyjson:json
type JSONData struct {
    Data []string
}
```

After define this struct run `easyjson <fileName-JSONData-is-defined>.go`. this will create an extra go file containg

```
func (v JSONData) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
func (v JSONData) MarshalEasyJSON(w *jwriter.Writer)
func (v *JSONData) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) errorfunc (v *JSONData) 
func UnmarshalEasyJSON(l *jlexer.Lexer)
```

those methods.
Then (un-)marshal using

```
d := &JSONData{}
d.UnmarshalJSON([]byte(`{"Data" : ["One", "Two", "Three"]} `))
// Or you could also use
// json.Unmarshal(data, d) this will also call this d.UnmarshalJSON
fmt.Println(d)
```

A full example is [here.](https://github.com/sadlil/experiments/tree/master/go/easyjson)

Comment: My json blob is quite big. `encoding/json` seems to be quite slow. So trying out `easyjson` as they claim it to be 3x-5x faster than `encoding/json`.

Comment: @sadlil, why would it be "better if you use encoding/json"?

Answer (score 7):

Well, easyJson is 4 times faster than normal json(as per its documets) ,in our organization we have used it extensively and yes its faster. Here is a small example to get started. my current directory name is **easyJson**

> vim easyjson.go

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import ej "random/golang/easyJson/model"

func main() {
 t1 := time.Now()
 var d ej.Data
 d.Name = "sharathbj"
 d.Age = 23
 data, _ := d.MarshalJSON()
 fmt.Println(string(data))
 fmt.Println("elapsedTime:", time.Now().Sub(t1))
}
```

create a directory named model ,where your structures are defined and new go file models.go

> mkdir model
>
> vim models.go

```
package easyJson

//easyjson:json
type Data struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Age  int    `json:"age"`
}
```

Now run command to create a easyjson file (**-all** specified to reference all the structure inside a given file)

> easyjson -all model/models.go

now a new file will be generated **models_easyjson.go** using which marshaling/unmarshaling will be referenced

> go run easyjson.go

[image]

To compare easyjson with normal encoding/json ,below is the code

> vim normaljson.go

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "time"
   "encoding/json"
    model "random/golang/easyJson/model"
 )
 func main() {
   t1 := time.Now()
   var d model.Data
   d.Name = "sharathbj"
   d.Age = 23
   data, _ := json.Marshal(d)
   fmt.Println(string(data))
   fmt.Println("elapsedTime:", time.Now().Sub(t1))
 }
```

[image]

Clearly easyjson is 7 micro second faster than normal json ,and you will see its impact when you do it for bigger structures , u can see the source code below .
 https://github.com/sharathbj/random/tree/master/golang/easyJson

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I installed using the instructions from the README.md file:

> go get github.com/mailru/easyjson/...

Then I created a directory in my GOPATH for this example:

> $GOPATH/github.com/jpudney/stack-overflow/40587860

```
tree  .                                              
.
├── main.go
└── mypackage
    ├── example.go
    └── example_easyjson.go
```

In mypackage/example.go I have the following code:

```
package mypackage

//easyjson:json
type JSONData struct {
    Data []string
}
```

Then, within the mypackage directory I ran the following command from the README:

> easyjson -all `<file>`.go

Where I replace `<file>` with example. So ended up running the following:

```
easyjson -all example.go
```

This results in a file called `example_easyjson.go` which contains the generated code.

I then created a `main.go` file to us the generated code. The contents of which is:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jpudney/stack-overflow/40587860/mypackage"
)

func main() {

    var data mypackage.JSONData
    jsonBlob := `{"Data" : ["One", "Two", "Three"]}`

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonBlob), &data)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(data.Data)

}
```

I build and ran this file and it outputted the data as expected:

```
$ go build -o test
$ ./test
[One Two Three]
```

Comment: You are using encoding/json's Unmarshal, not generated.

Comment: No, that's fine. From docs "easyjson also generates MarshalJSON and UnmarshalJSON funcs for Go struct types compatible with the standard json.Marshaler and json.Unmarshaler interfaces. Please be aware that using the standard json.Marshal / json.Unmarshal for marshaling/unmarshaling will incur a significant performance penalty when compared to using easyjson.Marshal / easyjson.Unmarshal."

Answer (score 0):

To serialize:

```
rawBytes, err := easyjson.Marshal(yourObject)
```

But internally it will create a new byte array so if you can dump to writer then use `easyjson.MarshalToWriter()` or even `easyjson.MarshalToHTTPResponseWriter()`:

```
_, _, err = easyjson.MarshalToHTTPResponseWriter(yourObject, w)
```

To deserialize:

```
err = easyjson.Unmarshal(rawBytes, yourObject)
```

See their documentation https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mailru/easyjson@v0.7.7#Marshal